# Home button Functionality in android

Tags: android

**What i am doing**:: I am trying to bring the functionality of a home button in some other button onclick

---

1. I know when we press home button in android app exits !

**`So Some function is invoked in android to perform this functionality`**

---

- Now i have a Button

---

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


    }

});
```

- I need to do onclick of this button i need to call this function
- How can i do this ?

Comment: Not Clear. What has Home Button got to do with your custom button

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    }
});
```

Comment: You beat it to be by mere seconds! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(homeIntent);

    }

});
```